# Elipsis dots are not showing with 3 Elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 elements
1: Text
2: download button
3: upload button

The text should truncate with elipsis once it reaches the container of the download button.
However, it is truncating but I can't get to show the 3 dots of the elipsis.

-Expected result: before the download button, the text stops and three dots are shown
-Actual result: text stops right after the download button.

I made a fiddle to show the live code where the problem occurs https://jsfiddle.net/ndyaw8tc/

```
<div class="uploader-container">
  <div class="file-name-preview">
      <p class="file-placeholder">really really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really ng textreally really longng textreally really longng textreally really longlong text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="download-container">
    <i class="material-icons" >
      file_download
    </i>
  </div>
  <div class="upload-button-container">
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="btn-upload" mat-button>
      UPLOAD
    </button>
  </div>
  <input type=file id="file-uploader" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileInput>
</div>
```

css

```
#file-uploader {
  display: none;
}

.uploader-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.file-name-preview {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.upload-button-container {
  width: 26%;
}

.download-container {
  width: 9%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-placeholder {
  color: gray !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it on the wrong class. Try...

```
.file-placeholder {
  color: gray !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9pg2w4m/

```css
#file-uploader {
  display: none;
}

.uploader-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.file-name-preview {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.upload-button-container {
  width: 26%;
}

.download-container {
  width: 9%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-placeholder {
  color: gray !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploader-container">
  <div class="file-name-preview">
    <p class="file-placeholder">really really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really long textreally really ng textreally really longng textreally really longng textreally really longlong text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="download-container">
    <i class="material-icons">
      file_download
    </i>
  </div>
  <div class="upload-button-container">
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="btn-upload" mat-button>
      UPLOAD
    </button>
  </div>
  <input type=file id="file-uploader" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileInput>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition

Comment: if you add a width to it, you can set where it needs to be cut off